# Load a new exe with gdb

Tags: gdb, dos

I am currently trying to make use of gdb to disassemble an exe, and from my home, I start the application like such:

```
gdb "c:\file.exe"
```

And gdb starts and loads that file automatically.

Now the problem is that from where I am atm, the command prompt is disabled and thus I cannot run the terminal window with the filename as the argument.

The only thing I think can do atm is open the `gdb.exe` file directly and then load the exe with a command or something, from gdb itself.

Is there a command I can use to load the exe to debug from within the application itself rather than passing it as an argument?

```
(gdb) <some command> "c:\file.exe"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(gdb)`file c:\file.exe`

Answer (score 3):

To start debugging it , use the file command, as  @Arkaitz Jimenez said

If your file.exe is a running process, you can use the [attach](http://www-zeuthen.desy.de/dv/documentation/unixguide/infohtml/gdb/gdb_23.html) command